# How to trigger Bootstrap 3 data-toggle with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have form that has two check box elements. Those two will show/hide additional form elements depends if they are checked or not. Then I have tried to implement feature where user clicks on add new record. In that case all form data should be cleared out including those two check box elements. However, I get both elements to be unchecked but data-toggle didn't hide the elements. Here is example of my code:

```js
$('.account-type').on('change', checkFormFld);

function checkFormFld() {
  var checked = false,
    containerID = $(this).data('target'),
    checkboxes = $('.account-type');

  $('.account-type').each(function() {
    checked = checked || $(this).is(':checked');
  });

  $(containerID + ' :input').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
  checkboxes.prop('required', !checked); // Set required attribute to false.
}

$('#account_goback').on('click', clearForm);

function clearForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.frm-Submit')[0].reset();
  $('.frm-Submit .collapse').collapse('hide');
  $('.account-type').trigger('change', checkFormFld);
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="searchaccount_container" class="collapse in">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#saveaccount_container,#searchaccount_container">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> New Account
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="saveaccount_container" class="collapse">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="account_goback" id="account_goback" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#saveaccount_container,#searchaccount_container">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span> Go Back
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="fname"><span class="label label-primary">First Name:</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_firstname" id="frm_firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="lname"><span class="label label-primary">Last Name:</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_lastname" id="frm_lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="email"><span class="label label-primary">Email address:</span></label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control check-existence" name="frm_email" id="frm_email" placeholder="Enter email" maxlength="80" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="type"><span class="label label-primary">Account Type:</span></label>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="user">
            <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isuser" id="frm_isuser" class="account-type" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-account" required> 
            <span class="label label-default">User</span>
        </label>
        <label for="staff">
            <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isstaff" id="frm_isstaff" class="account-type" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#staff-account" required> 
            <span class="label label-info">Staff</span>
         </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user-account" class="collapse">
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="active"><span class="label label-default">Active User:<span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="frm_activeuser" id="frm_activeuser" required disabled>
          <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
          <option value="0">No</option>
          <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="admin"><span class="label label-default">System Admin:</span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="frm_systemadmin" id="frm_systemadmin" required disabled>
          <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
          <option value="0">No</option>
          <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="staff-account" class="collapse">
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="activestaff"><span class="label label-info">Active Staff:<span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="frm_activestaff" id="frm_activestaff" required disabled>
          <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
          <option value="0">No</option>
          <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
        <button type="submit" name="frmSaveaccount_submit" id="frmSaveaccount_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

If you run example and un-comment line of code in `clearForm` function you can see that hidden container will slide up but won't show up if I click again. Is there a way to achieve this to work with JQuery?

Comment: I think that example above is working as expected. I had to change `checkFormFld` function and to trigger once the user clicks on Go Back button. If anyone has better solution please let me know.

Comment: Guess will have to restructure the way you have `required` assigned to it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Collapse component methods...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-methods

```
$('.frm-Submit .collapse').collapse('toggle');
```

Comment: Do I need to check if they are visible or not? I have tried your solution and all I can see is that all form elements are disabled...

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is remove those classes which we need to collapse on **Go Back** Button. And remove attribute required as well

```
$('#user-account').removeClass('in');
$('#staff-account').removeClass('in');
$("#frm_isstaff").removeAttr('required'); // Set required attribute to false. 
$("#frm_activeuser").removeAttr('required'); // Set required attribute to false. 
$("#frm_systemadmin").removeAttr('required'); // Set required attribute to false.
```

---

```js
var $checkbox = $('.account-type');
$checkbox.on('change', function() {
  var checked = false,
    containerID = $(this).data('target');

  $checkbox.each(function() {
    checked = checked || $(this).is(':checked');
  });

  $('div' + containerID + ' :input').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked')); // Set disabled attribute on all input fields when check box is unchecked.
  $checkbox.prop('required', !checked); // Set required attribute to false. 
});

$('#account_new').on('click', clearForm);

function clearForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.frm-Submit')[0].reset();
  $('#user-account').removeClass('in');
  $('#staff-account').removeClass('in');
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="searchaccount_container" class="collapse in">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" name="account_new" id="account_new" data-target="#saveaccount_container,#searchaccount_container">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> New Account
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="saveaccount_container" class="collapse">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#saveaccount_container,#searchaccount_container">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span> Go Back
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="fname"><span class="label label-primary">First Name:</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_firstname" id="frm_firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="lname"><span class="label label-primary">Last Name:</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_lastname" id="frm_lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="email"><span class="label label-primary">Email address:</span></label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control check-existence" name="frm_email" id="frm_email" placeholder="Enter email" maxlength="80" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="type"><span class="label label-primary">Account Type:</span></label>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="user">
            <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isuser" id="frm_isuser" class="account-type" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-account" required> 
            <span class="label label-default">User</span>
        </label>
        <label for="staff">
            <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isstaff" id="frm_isstaff" class="account-type" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#staff-account" required> 
            <span class="label label-info">Staff</span>
         </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user-account" class="collapse">
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="active"><span class="label label-default">Active User:<span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="frm_activeuser" id="frm_activeuser" required disabled>
          <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
          <option value="0">No</option>
          <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="admin"><span class="label label-default">System Admin:</span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="frm_systemadmin" id="frm_systemadmin" required disabled>
          <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
          <option value="0">No</option>
          <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="staff-account" class="collapse">
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="activestaff"><span class="label label-info">Active Staff:<span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="frm_activestaff" id="frm_activestaff" required disabled>
          <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
          <option value="0">No</option>
          <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
        <button type="submit" name="frmSaveaccount_submit" id="frmSaveaccount_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Also, this is another solution that I got `$('.frm-Submit .collapse').collapse('hide');`

Comment: Small side note, this will work fine until I try to submit the form. If section was expanded and I click Go Back then come back and try to submit the other section it will require fields from the other section. That's where my onchange function should take care of that.

Comment: I got what you are saying. give me few minutes :)

Comment: My check box function should be more dynamic/capable to adjust in situations like this. I'm working on some solution as well. Thank you!

Comment: @espresso_coffee, I got it long time ago but was struggling with a typo. Was using `frm_isuser` instead of `from_activeuser`

Comment: You will have to toggle the `require` and will do it soon